# detailview screen can not open with pushViewController in a tableview

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, pushviewcontroller

I have a tabbar in my project and each tab bar has a tableview.
I want to open a detail screen when click a row in a tableview as follows. But nothing happens.
Where's the mistake I'm doing. How should I set up a logic.

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
DetailScreen *detail = [[DetailScreen alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailScreen" bundle:nil];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
[detail release];
```

}

Answer (score 2):

There are many possible reasons nothing is happening when you click on a cell.

- Put a break point in this method. Is It even being called?
- After the App has stopped at the breakpoint, go to the console type `po detail` after the instance is initialised. Make sure it's not (null)
- Also try typing `po [self navigationController]` to check whether the navigation controller exists.

You've probably not got a navigation controller. How are you creating the tabbarcontroller? in interface builder or through code in the AppDelegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method?

Have you done this?

```
    YourViewController *yourVC = [[YourViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourViewController" bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:yourVC];

    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navigationController, nil];
```

Comment: I'm creating the tabbarcontroller in another class not in app delegate because the tab bar screen is not the first screen.

Comment: Are you embedding your ViewController in a UINavigationController?

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
     DetailScreen *detail = [[DetailScreen alloc] init];
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
     [detail release];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you don't have a navigation controller so

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
```

will not work.

use

```
[self.view addSubview:detail.view]
```

or

```
[self presentModalViewController:detail animated:YES];
```

instead

Answer (score 0):

If your project is **UITabBarViewController** based application, i dont think your can navigate to   another view using pushViewController unless you have **navigationController** in your project.

Answer (score 0):

Add your view controller(your table view containing controller) into navigation controller and then start using

```
DetailScreen *detail = [[DetailScreen alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailScreen" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
```

Comment: @sixeightzero what's wrong with my answer? I did not understand what you editted.

Comment: Click on where it says: edited x hours ago. This will show you what changes were made. I applied syntax highlighting to your answer to make it easier to read and to separate code from text.

Answer (score -2):

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
```

Instead move your detail push code to another method and call:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(myMethod:) withObject:nil]
```